# How to deal with failover and stale data when using Azure Redis cache

Tags: c#, .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I started using distributed Azure Redis cache in my project.

Here is my startup config:

```
if (cacheEnvironmentLocal.HasValue && cacheEnvironmentLocal.Value)
            {
                services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            }
            else
            {              
                services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
                {
                 options.Configuration = cacheConnectionString;
                });
            }
```

I use AddStackExchangeRedisCache which already has the default retry and timeout policy so that is fine.

As i understand it also has the ForceReconnect implemented so that the connection is recreated if there is some issue.

I'm using the Standard tier of Azure Redis meaning I have two nodes (primary and replica) and its clear that in most of the cases one of them will work, but in some bigger issues (some hardware or network issue that is causing the cache not to be available for some time) it could be that both will fail.

**Hypotetical example im worried about:**

When the cache is down i try to remove something from cache but I get an exception and continue with my code.

But then when the cache is back and running, I have stale data in the cache.

Next time i try to get this value it will be an old one and the application will act weird.

Get and Set this is ok because if the cache is not working I will just catch the exception and continue, but the remove is the issue because the data in the cache is stale.

Here is the code of my remove function:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Removes the object from the cache.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the vaule.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="id">Id of the object.</param>
        public void Remove<T>(string id)
            where T : class
        {

            var key = GenerateKey(id, GetTypeName<T>());
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            {
                logger.Warning("Id or type for the cache were not provided properly");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
               distributedCache.Remove(key);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                logger.Error(new CacheException(Error_02.CacheRemoveFailed, e));
            }
        }
```

For now I catch the possible exception and continue. I also do that for the get and set.

The articles I read but couldn't find the answer:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-failover#how-do-i-make-my-application-resilient

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/framework/resiliency/reliability-patterns#resiliency

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#azure-cache-for-redis

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-best-practices-connection#using-forcereconnect-with-stackexchangeredis

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-configure#memory-policies

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-administration#reboot

**My question is:**

**Is there a way to clear the cache(FLUSHDB) programatically when such issue occurs, so when the cache is back again i have a clean plate?**

Answer (score 2):

While there is no built-in feature to do that, you could implement that as part of your code or have an external service do that.

Ideally, for the scenario that you've mentioned, you should retry the key removal instead of continuing or queue it for removal to ensure consistency while not blocking execution.

Based on the code that you've shared, your cache implementation could have the `get` operation to return the value if present or null on error and other operations like `update` or `delete` could just queue the operation and process them on the side. This separate thread could wait and handle for failures as required.

Depending on your scenario, you could also set keys to expire after a certain period which would ensure they are deleted and ensure your application fetches the latest value.